# Dynamic updating label in .NET MAUI for Android

Tags: c#, android, maui, .net-7.0

I've been working on a simple app in MAUI to work with vibrations. I basically run vibrations in patterns based on user  input.
The thing is that i want to display time when next vibration will ocure.
I haven't seen any topic that covers case like this after 2 days of research.

I've got my model class named VibExecutor with Start method which runs selected vibrations and sets public filed NextRun with DateTime type.

```
public partial class VibExecutor : IDisposable
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer Timer { get; set; }
    public VibProg CurrentVibProg { get; set; }
    public DateTime? NextRun { get; set; }
         
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Timer?.Dispose();
    }

    public void Start(VibProg vibProg)
    {
        if (vibProg == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("vibProg can not be a null");

        CurrentVibProg = vibProg;

        vibProg.Init();

        NextRun = vibProg.NextRun();

        if (NextRun.HasValue)
        {
            Timer = new()
            {
                AutoReset = false
            };

            Timer.Elapsed += TimerCallback;

            InitTimerForNextRun(NextRun);
        }
    }

    private void InitTimerForNextRun(DateTime? when)
    {
        Timer.Stop();

        if (when.HasValue)
        {
            Timer.Interval = Math.Max(1, (when - DateTime.Now).Value.TotalMilliseconds);
            Timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentVibProg.MakeNoise();
        InitTimerForNextRun(CurrentVibProg.
            NextRun());
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        InitTimerForNextRun(null);
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return Timer.Enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

In MainPage class I want to access it and update the text in the label in view whenever the field was modified in runtime.

[UPDATE]
MainPage class

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public IList<VibProg> VibProgList { get; set; }
    public VibProg SelectedProgram { get; set; }
    public static VibExecutor VibExecutor { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindPicker();

        periodEntry.TextChanged += ParameterChanged;
        durationEntry.TextChanged += ParameterChanged;

        programPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += ProgramPickerChangedValue;

        startButton.Clicked += Start;

        cancelButton.Clicked += Cancel;
    }

    public void Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HideOptions(sender, e);

        VibExecutor = new();
        VibExecutor.Start(SelectedProgram);

        LockStartButton(sender, e);
        UnlockCancelButton(sender, e);
    }

    public void Cancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VibExecutor.Stop();
        VibExecutor.Dispose();

        UnlockStartButton(sender, e);

        ShowOptions(sender, e);

        LockCancelButton(sender, e);
    }

    #region Picker functionalities
    public void BindPicker()
    {
        VibProgList = VibProgRegister.All;

        // Set the binding context to the current page
        BindingContext = this;

        // Set the binding properties for the Picker
        programPicker.SetBinding(Picker.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("VibProgList"));
        programPicker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Name");
    }

    public void ProgramPickerChangedValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedProgram = (VibProg)programPicker.SelectedItem;

        ShowOptions(sender, e);

        int periodS = SelectedProgram.PeriodMs / 1000;
        int durationS = SelectedProgram.DurationMs / 1000;

        periodLabel.Text = SelectedProgram.PeriodDescription;
        periodEntry.Text = periodS.ToString();

        durationLabel.Text = SelectedProgram.DurationDescription;
        durationEntry.Text = durationS.ToString();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Parameters handling
    public void ParameterChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var period = periodEntry.Text;
        var duration = durationEntry.Text;
        _ = int.TryParse(period, out int _period);
        _ = int.TryParse(duration, out int _duration);

        bool periodRes = ValidateParameter(_period);
        bool durationRes = ValidateParameter(_duration);

        if (periodRes && durationRes)
        {
            SelectedProgram.PeriodMs = _period * 1000;
            SelectedProgram.DurationMs = _duration * 1000;

            UnlockStartButton(sender, e);
        }

        else
        {
            LockStartButton(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateParameter(int param)
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 20;

        if (param > max || param < min) 
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Locking and unlocking buttons functions
    private void UnlockCancelButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancelButton.IsEnabled = true;
        cancelButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Parse("Red");
    }

    private void LockStartButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startButton.IsEnabled = false;
        startButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Parse("DarkGrey");
    }

    private void UnlockStartButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startButton.IsEnabled = true;
        startButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Parse("Green");
    }

    private void LockCancelButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancelButton.IsEnabled = false;
        cancelButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Parse("DarkGrey");
    }
    #endregion

    #region Showing and hiding programs options
    private void ShowOptions(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        options.IsVisible = true;
    }

    private void HideOptions(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        options.IsVisible = false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FoxNet.GardenDefender.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Label Text="Select program:" />
            <Picker x:Name="programPicker" Title="Program type"/>

            <StackLayout x:Name="options" IsVisible="False">
                <Label x:Name="periodLabel" />
                <Entry x:Name="periodEntry" MaxLength="2" Keyboard="Numeric" />
                <Label x:Name="durationLabel" />
                <Entry x:Name="durationEntry" MaxLength="2" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Label x:Name="errorLabel" Text="Enter values from given ranges!" TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" IsVisible="False"/>

            <Button 
                x:Name="startButton"
                Text="Start"
                IsEnabled="False"
                Clicked="Start"
                BackgroundColor="DarkGray"
            />

            <Button 
                x:Name="cancelButton"
                IsEnabled="False"
                Text="Cancel"
                Clicked="Cancel"
                BackgroundColor="DarkGray"
            />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Is this Model bound to your View somehow?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out way how to do this, so if you have any idea it will be much appreciated

Comment: use data binding.  This is well documented.  Its difficult to offer specific advice based on what you've posted.  Is that code snippet part of the code behind for `MainPage`?  Is `NextRun` a public property?  Are you using MVVM?

Comment: my structure of files is like this: xaml file as View, MainPage.xaml.cs as a ViewModel and VibExecutor as a Model class that runs timers for selected type of vibration to run them based on given interval. Mentioned above Start method is a part of VibExecutor class. NextRun is a public propert (I've updated the post). I'm trying to apply MVVM but it's my first app so I'm new to it.

Comment: Please add an UPDATE section to your question, containing the details in that comment. This keeps the question up-to-date. And info can be better formatted in the question. ALSO add the MainPage XAML you want to be dynamically updated. And show MainPage's constructor - this is where `BindingContext` should be set. OR if there is XAML that mentions `BindingContext`, show that. ALSO add a link to whatever MVVM doc or example you are trying to follow. I recommend getting **some MVVM example working** first. Doing so should teach you what you are asking here.

Comment: updated that. I haven't followed one specific kind of MVVM, mostly I was looking at Microsoft docs to see what's that and I assumed that it's kind of set of rules to organize project. Just like BOs, DTO and Service in web apps. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you use [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm) to achieve this. Then we need to add the most code of `MainPage.xaml.cs` to the `ViewModel` for this page. For example, we need to use `Command` to bind to the Buttons on the Page.

For example:

```
     public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public DateTime _nestRunTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime NestRunTime
    {
        set
        {
            _nestRunTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NestRunTime));
        }
        get { return _nestRunTime; }
    }

    //**********************************

    public IList<VibProg> VibProgList { get; set; }
    public VibProg SelectedProgram { get; set; }
    public static VibExecutor VibExecutor { get; set; }


    public ICommand StartCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand CancelCommand { get; set; }



    public MyViewModel()
    {

        StartCommand = new Command(startMethod);
        CancelCommand = new Command(cancelMethod);
    }

    private void cancelMethod()
    {
        // add  the code of  method `Cancel` here
    }

    private void startMethod()
    {
        // add  the code of  method `Start` here

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
        <Button 
            x:Name="startButton"
            Text="Start"
            IsEnabled="False"
            Command="{Binding StartCommand}"
            BackgroundColor="DarkGray"
        />

        <Button 
            x:Name="cancelButton"
            IsEnabled="False"
            Text="Cancel"
            Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
            BackgroundColor="DarkGray"
        />
```

**Note:**

1.Remember to create an instance of the ViewModel and set `BindContext` for this page.

2.I just simply give you an example of the above code, you also need to convert some of `MainPage.xaml.cs`'s code  and add it to MVVM.

And based on the code you shared, if you don't want the code to change a lot, you can simply add a property(e.g. `NestRunTime`) on `MainPage.xaml.cs` and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this page.Then the UI will refresh itself once changing the value of the added property `NestRunTime`.

Besides, you can use [MessageCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter) to send the value of DateTime `NextRun` to `MainPage`.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   // add property NestRunTime here
     public DateTime _nestRunTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime NestRunTime
    {
        set { 
            _nestRunTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NestRunTime));
        }
        get { return _nestRunTime; }
    }

    public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext = this;


        //receive message here
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<VibExecutor, DateTime>(this, "Time", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Message received", "arg=" + arg.ToString(), "OK");

            NestRunTime = arg;
        });
    }
}
```

In `VibExecutor.cs`, send message once getting the value of `NextRun`:

```
   public class VibExecutor: IDisposable 
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer Timer { get; set; }
        public VibProg CurrentVibProg { get; set; }
        public DateTime? NextRun { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Timer?.Dispose();
        }

        public void Start(VibProg vibProg)
        {
            if (vibProg == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("vibProg can not be a null");

            CurrentVibProg = vibProg;

            vibProg.Init();

            NextRun = vibProg.NextRun();

            //send time to MainPage
            MessagingCenter.Send<VibExecutor, DateTime>(this, "Hi", (DateTime)NextRun);

            //Some additional code is omitted for code simplicity

        }
    }
```

Usage example:

```
  <Label  Text="{Binding NestRunTime}" />
```